# Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.7'` succeeds before bundling.

Tags: ruby, json

I tried to create a new project and I get this error.
What does this mean?

> Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.7 for inspection.
>   Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
>   An error occured while installing json (1.7.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.7'` succeeds before bundling.

Answer (score 3):

My *guess* is that the json gem requires a C compiler and you don't have one. You could find out more by typing `gem install json -v 1.7.7` though.

Comment: Also make sure that you've got the DevKit installed (as I'm assuming this is on Windows) and that the path to DevKit is part of your `PATH` system variable.

Comment: Where else do you find paths like `C:/RailsInstaller` aside from Windows?